# Add array of objects to PHPExcel template

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, phpexcel

I'm currently pulling an array of objects from my database with the intention of each object representing a row in a PHPExcel template.
The data is as follows:

```
[
    {
        name: test,
        age: test,
        other_info: test,
        my_info: test
    },
    {
        name: test,
        age: test,
        other_info: test,
        my_info: test
    },
    {
        name: test,
        age: test,
        other_info: test,
        my_info: test
    },
]
```

The rows in my Excel sheet start at 17 - so the first object would be entered in row 17, the second object in the array would be entered in row 18 and so on. However, the columns I wish to add to are not all next to each other, so its difficult to loop. For example, the name field of the first object should be entered into `C17`, while the age field should be entered into `F17` and the other_info field should be entered into `J17` and my_info should be in `L17`. The second object would then be entered into the same columns but the next row and so on.

I have tried looping through the array but that doesn't allow me to skip the columns, only add to consecutive columns and rows;

```
foreach ($array as $rowArray) {
    $columnID = 'C';
    $rowID = 17;
    foreach ($rowArray as $columnValue) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID, $columnValue);
        $rowID++;
    } 
}
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$json = '[
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "age":"age1",
                "other_info":"other_info1",
                "my_info":"my_info1"
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "age": "age2",
                "other_info": "other_info2",
                "my_info": "my_info2"
            }
        ]';

$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();
$cells = ['name' => 'C', 'age' => 'F', 'other_info' => 'J', 'my_info' => 'L'];
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$rowID = 17;
foreach($array as $rowArray) {
    foreach ($rowArray as $index => $columnValue) {
        $col = $cells[$index].$rowID;
        $phpExcelObject
          ->getActiveSheet()
          ->setCellValue((string)$col, $columnValue);
    }
    $rowID++;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".. which is weird because my understanding is that the true section of it states that its an array as opposed to a string. Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: json_decode() expects a string as first parameter, have a look at [the official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Your data is a bit weird, its no valid json (but looks like it should be) and it's not a PHP array of objects. Please compare with my example json string.

Comment: Realised my issue, I had extra fields in my actual data (such as 'ID') which were interfering. This answer is correct thank you for your help @Chris